# Set Operations in Python and code optimisation

Tags: python, set

I am trying to write a generic code to perform set operation on any number of input files.

normally for any set operation (where I already limit the number of input files), I use something like this.

```
my_set1 = set(map(str.strip, open('filename1.txt')))
my_set2 = set(map(str.strip, open('filename2.txt')))
common = myset1.intersection(my_set2)
```

Where each file has only one column.

Now what I am aiming is to put all the set theory functions in it. Something like.

```
python set.py -i file1,file2,file3,file4 -o inter
```

These inputs are taken from the user.

Actually user can define the number of input files and the kind of operation he will like.

If anyone of you can show me how it can be done, I can write for the other operations myself like for union and difference

Answer (score 2):

The `set.intersection()` and [`set.update_intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection_update) methods take any iterable, not just sets.

Since you are only interested in the end-product (the intersection between the files) you'd best use `set.intersection_update()` here.

Start with one set, then keep updating it with the rest of the files:

```
with open(files[0]) as infh:
    myset = set(map(str.strip, infh))

for filename in files[1:]:
    with open(filename) as infh:
        myset.intersection_update(map(str.strip, infh))
```

You can make the method used dynamic based on the command-line switch:

```
ops = {'inter': set.intersection_update,
       'union': set.update,
       'diff': set.difference_update}

with open(files[0]) as infh:
    myset = set(map(str.strip, infh))

for filename in files[1:]:
    with open(filename) as infh:
        ops[operation](myset, map(str.strip, infh))
```

Comment: could you please explain why you read the first set alone? shouldn't it work with just the list of sets?

Comment: @SamyArous: the intersection between an empty set and anything else is an empty set; you have to start with one of the files if you want intersections to work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So if I understand correctly, I can just put all the sections together in one code file and execute it, right? Don't I need a parser or something?

Comment: set.intersection({1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {2, 4}) seems to be giving the right result. am I missing something?

Comment: @Angelo; I gave you two different variants; the first block uses `myset.update_intersection()` directly. The second block improves on the first by making the operation dynamic.

Comment: @SamyArous: That's because you are using the unbound method and passing in the first set as the `self` parameter.

Comment: @MartijnPietersThank for the explaination.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Excuse me ofr my ignorance. I have three files namely file1,file2, and file3. I had put one of the variants of your code in a set.py. Now how can I execute it.

Comment: @Angelo: `files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']` should do it.

Comment: But How about parsing the inputs?

Comment: @Angelo: take a look at the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html); if you struggle with that module, ask a new question.

Comment: Thank's.  Here is what I am doing#!/usr/bin/python

files = ['set1', 'set2', 'set3']

with open(files[0]) as infh:
    myset = set(map(str.strip, infh))

for filename in files[1:]:
    with open(filename) as infh:
        myset.update_intersection(map(str.strip, infh))                                                                               I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "set.py", line 10, in <module>
    myset.update_intersection(map(str.strip, infh))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'update_intersection'

Comment: @Angelo: Ah, yes, I made a mistake and swapped the keywords in that method. Corrected now.